# MouseMoveEvent not trigger when button is disabled

Tags: qt, qt5, mousemove, disabled-control

How force mouseMoveEvent when QPushButton is disabled?

I have disabled QPushButton on QScrollArea and on swipe mouseMoveEvent is not trigged.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eventFilter` like this:

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event) override;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QPushButton>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QPushButton *button = new QPushButton{this};
    button->installEventFilter(this);
    button->setMouseTracking(true);
    button->setText("bla");
    button->setDisabled(true);

    QWidget *widget = new QWidget{this};
    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout{widget};
    layout->setContentsMargins(50, 50, 50, 50);
    layout->addWidget(button);
    this->setCentralWidget(widget);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove)
    {
        qDebug() << "mouse move" << static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event)->pos();
        return true;
    }
    else
        return QMainWindow::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

Comment: It almost works. The mouse position is returned strangely. For example, when I move vertically down, I get values sometimes smaller and sometimes bigger.
QPoint(225,343)
QPoint(227,335)
QPoint(226,356)
QPoint(227,348)
QPoint(226,369)
QPoint(224,361)
QPoint(226,374)
QPoint(229,355)
QPoint(232,368)
QPoint(233,352) 

Comment: How are you getting the position? `qDebug() << "mouse move" << static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event)->pos();` works for me.

Comment: I have exactly the same.
Return values are valid for mouseMoveEvent () and event ().

Comment: Then maybe consider sharing your code. My small example does not have that behavior.

Comment: When moving my finger, I change the value of the scrollbar and it then returns the position very strangely.

Comment: I can be because the scroll bar's position is changed as you said. But without the actual code, I cannot help you much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222946/discussion-between-ngoc-minh-nguyen-and-jaroslaw-pietras).